# QML uncheck checked button in ExclusiveGroup

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have three buttons that are in an `ExclusiveGroup`:

```
ExclusiveGroup {id: group}
Button{
    checkable: true
    exclusiveGroup: group
}
Button{
    checkable: true
    exclusiveGroup: group
}
Button{
    checkable: true
    exclusiveGroup: group
}
```

They are obviously all unchecked before I click any of them, but how can I uncheck them once one of them are checked? Do I really need to add another button that, once checked, produces the behaviour that would apply when none of the other buttons are checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the [`current`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-exclusivegroup.html#current-prop) property of `ExclusiveGroup`:

> **The currently selected object**. Defaults to the first checked object bound to the ExclusiveGroup. **If** there is **none**, then it **defaults to null**.

**Hence the approach is to uncheck the current button by setting the `current` property to `null`, whenever you need it.**

In the following example I'm removing checking state as it happens, which is clearly more an excercise than a real use case. But it gives a grasp of the approach, anyway:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 200

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button{
            id: but1
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
        Button{
            id: but2
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
        Button{
            id: but3
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: group
        }
    }

    ExclusiveGroup {
        id: group

        onCurrentChanged: {
            if(current != null) {
                console.info("button checked...no!")
                current = null
                //current.checked = false    <--- also this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Clear checked button if button clicked but checked state not changed.

```
ButtonGroup {
    buttons: [button1, button2, ...]
    property bool buttonChangeFlag: false
    onClicked: {
        if (!buttonChangeFlag) {
            checkedButton = null
        }
        buttonChangeFlag = false
    }
    onCheckedButtonChanged: {
        buttonChangeFlag = true
    }
}
```